# Windows tar compress command doesnt appear to include subdirectories

Tags: windows-10, powershell, compression, tar, gzip

I am trying to compress all files and folders in the current folder (on my Windows 10 environment) so I can extract them on my Raspbian environment. Im using a Powershell script with the `tar` command

`tar -cvzf output.tar.gz .`

From all that I read, tar is recursive by default, but Im finding that despite my best efforts I cant get it to compress anything other than the files in the root of the folder.

If I populate the directory with some test files and folders (named `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `subfolder` respectively, which also contains two test files) then `tar` works as expected and includes the subfolder!

I suspected that this was perhaps a privileges issue, so I ran powershell as Administrator but the result was the same.

The contents of the directory are coming from a Publish from Visual Studio -- thats the only thing I can see which might be causing the problem. I just dont know what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe the files are beeing used and blocked for reading. Have you tried copying them to another location?

Comment: try with `tar -cvzf output.tar.gz *`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions chaps. Unfortunately tried both with the same results each time.